# ObjectMapper Error when Upgrade .Net Core 2.2 & ASP.NET Boilerplate 4.5 to .Net Core 3.1 & ASP.NET Boilerplate 5.13

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

ObjectMapper works on .Net Core 2.2 & ASP.NET Boilerplate 4.5 -> OK
but works on .Net Core 3.1 & ASP.NET Boilerplate 5.13 -> Error

Are there any other settings that must be done？

My Error Message:

```
 "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nProd -> ProdDto\r\ncom.myproject.Core.Models.Prod -> com.myproject.Application.Prod.Dto.ProdDto"
```

My AppService:

```
public override async Task<ProdDto> GetAsync(EntityDto<int> input)
{  
    try
    {
        var entity = await _prodManager.GetProdByIdAsync(input.Id);

        var result = ObjectMapper.Map<ProdDto>(entity);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

My Module:

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(AbpAutoMapperModule))]
public class ProdApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(ProdApplicationModule).GetAssembly();

        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(thisAssembly);

        Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
            cfg => cfg.AddMaps(thisAssembly)
        );
    }
}
```

My Profile:

```
public class ProdMapProfile : Profile
{
    public ProdMapProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Core.Models.Prod, ProdDto>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a missing mapping. If you add `CreateMap<Core.Models.ProdBranch, ProdDto>();` to `ProdMapProfile` it would be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, error message is wrong.
I fixed it.

Comment: Is `ProdMapProfile` in the same project as `ProdApplicationModule`?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project.

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, this is my company project, may not be able to put it on GitHub.

Comment: I asked you to create a repro project, not put your company project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I've updated to net core 3.1, to solve it you need to map the result of your `Get`, see the modification on your code

```
public override async Task<ProdDto> GetAsync(EntityDto<int> input)
{  
    try
    {
        var entity = await _prodManager.GetProdByIdAsync(input.Id).Result;

        var result = ObjectMapper.Map<ProdDto>(entity);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

It happens because it is trying to map the async response, when you add `.result` it works.

Comment: I can't add ```.result``` because of Compiler Error CS1061

Comment: I tried. But it still error like ```My Error Message```
And It seems that ```await```  and ```.Result``` cannot exist at the same time. So I remove ```await``` and keep ```.Result```

Comment: And I tried to build testDto1 & testDto2 (only the same two fields, in the same project, add in ProdMapProfile) to test.  When I run ```var result2 = ObjectMapper.Map<TestDto2>(testDto1);``` in GetAsync(), it still error (```Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping```)